# Team Fortress 2 won't install on custom location

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why can’t I install TF2 in a non-default game library location?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95462/why-cant-i-install-tf2-in-a-non-default-game-library-location)

I am running a system with one 128GB SSD (used for my system and programs installed) and a couple of HDD's (for everything else, including games since these would fill up my tiny 128GB disk otherwise).

I do however have steam installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\ since I do try to keep programs there (more semantic and saves a lot of problems in general).
I keep my games installed in D:\Steam.

Usually when I install a game via steam I can choose where to install it (I'm fairly new to gaming/steam but have so far done this successfully to Magicka and Planetside 2, which are both located in D:\Steam\SteamApps\common). However when I try to install TF2 it doesn't give me the option to install in a custom location, it just says:

> You are about to install Team Fortress 2.
>
> Disk space required: 10616 MB
>
> Disk space Available: 54379 MB
>
> ...
>
> Next> | CANCEL

The available disk space indicates my C drive, and I have tried installing it and it does install on the C drive.

It might be worth mentioning that I did have TF2 installed about a year ago when I used an HDD as system drive, there for installing TF2 in the standard Steam directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps).

Another thing that bothers me is that when I tried to install TF2 in the standard directory it didn't make a folder inside the SteamApps directory like my other installations but ended up in a bunch of different files laying around in the SteamApps directory. Hm.

I want TF2 to be installed in D:\Steam\SteamApps\ like my other games. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I have this same issue, it's the only game that does this!  Here's the duplicate question, not sure why it wasn't here in the first place: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95462/why-cant-i-install-tf2-in-a-non-default-game-library-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the old-fashioned way by using the `mklink` command. Before steam introduced multiple 'Game libraries' this was the only way to get steam to install games on other hard drives.

#### Quick explanation of mklink

The syntax of the mklink command is

> mklink /D <link> <source>

- Where *source* is where the steam files **are**, and *link* is where you want steam to **think** they are
- `/D` tells mklink to create a *Directory* Link, instead of a *File* link.

#### How I moved my entire Steamapps folder to my D drive

- Shutdown Steam, navigate to the steam directory, and cut `steamapps` to another hard drive, say `D:\Steam\steamapps`. (this may take a while).
- Using `Command Prompt`, Navigate to the Steam directory. For example

  > cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam"
- Using the `mklink` command, create a *Directory Symbolic Link* to point to the new steamapps folder.

  > mklink /D "steamapps" "D:\Steam\steamapps"

If you go into your steam directory, you'll see what looks like a shortcut to the `steamapps` folder. Navigating into it, Explorer still thinks you're under the `C:` directory. However, all the data is now in the `D:` directory.

I don't know how steam handles having two Game libraries point to the same location (effectively this is what we're doing here). you may need to remove the `D:` drive's game library first (cutting out the game files first, and merging them back in after), or just choose another folder location.

Comment: I got the error message "Cannot create a file when that file already exists". Ideas?

Comment: At what point do you get this message? If it's when you are trying to create the link, make sure you've cut the *entire* steamapps directory (i.e, don't leave the folder there)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, I get the error in cmd when I try the mklink command. I have completely removed the folder, yet it is complaining.

Comment: OH, whoops, I've put the directories around the wrong way! it should be `<link> <source>` not `<source> <link>` my bad! I've edited my answer, let me know how you go :)

Comment: Yep - that did the trick! :D Thank you very much! Have a good day! :)